# Use value of one key in object as the value of another key in the same object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object where I would like to use value of one key in the value of another key

```
var paths = {
  src = '/home'
  styles: src + '/styles',
  scripts: src + '/scripts'
}
```

This does not work.

```
var paths = {
  src = '/home'
  styles: this.src + '/styles',
  scripts: this.src + '/scripts'
  ...
}
```

Does not work either as this relates to global scope not paths scope.

this works but would rather not have multiple objects

```
var app  = {
  src: '/home'
}

var paths = {
  styles: app.src + '/styles',
  scripts: app.src + '/scripts'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var paths = {
  src: '/home'
};
paths.styles = paths.src + '/styles';
paths.scripts = paths.src + '/scripts';
console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct a simple function, with `src` as a parameter and return the object, like this

```
function createPaths(source) {
    return {
        src: source,
        styles: source + '/styles',
        scripts: source + '/scripts'
    };
}
```

And you can get the object by calling the function, like this

```
var app = createPaths('/home');
```